# Htaccess: Use https://www. with exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect every request in my website to **https://www.** and also tunnel everything to index.php

There are two exceptions for the urls of the like:

**http://www.example.com/share/AAAAA**

**https://www.example.com/share/BBBBB**

and

**http://www.example.com/loader/AAAAA**

**https://www.example.com/loader/BBBBB**

(AAAA and BBBB can be anything)

For these urls i want it to always use **www** but the **https** must not be mandatory. They should work both on **http** and **https**.
This is my htaccess so far:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

RewriteEngine On

#USE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(share/|loader/)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,QSA]

#ALWAYS USE www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rest=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is working for the rest of the pages, except for the exceptions.
If i enter

**http://www.example.com/share/AAAAA**

in the browser it redirects me to

**https://www.example.com/index.php?rest=share/AAAAA**

So not only it adds **https**, but it also shows the ?rest stuff in the url. Note that the ?rest= problem is not happening with all the other links. This should be tunneling in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` variable:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
RewriteEngine On

#USE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(share/|loader/)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

#ALWAYS USE www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rest=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please explain what's the meaning of the !\s/+ rule?

Comment: That is actually a negation. By placing `!` in the pattern we negate something. `!\s/+` is part after `GET`i.e. space and first `/` that comes just before `share` in URL